# WCF message logging - add filters with XPath queries

Tags: wcf, logging, xpath, filter, message

I have a WCF service with the following contract:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace="http://myNamespace.org/")]
public interface IMyService
{
    [OperationContract]
    string Invert(string s);

    [OperationContract]
    string ToUpper(string s);
}
```

Clients call both methods, `Invert` and `ToUpper`. Imagine I want to use message logging, but the only method I'm interested in is `ToUpper` as the other method is heavily used and logging all the messages would blow the log ;)

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa967569%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), I read how to filter the messages that are written into the log. But I must be doing something wrong as my log remains empty... My config looks like this

```
<system.serviceModel>
  ...
  <diagnostics>
    <messageLogging logEntireMessage="true" logMessagesAtServiceLevel="false" logMalformedMessages="true" logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true">
      <filters>
        <add xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">/soap:Envelope/soap:Header/a:Action[starts-with(text(),'http://myNamespace.org/IMyService/ToUpper')]</add>
      </filters>
    </messageLogging>
  </diagnostics>

</system.serviceModel>

<system.diagnostics>
  <sources>
    <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging">
      <listeners>
        <add name="ServiceModelTraceListener" />
      </listeners>
    </source>
  </sources>
  <sharedListeners>
    <add initializeData="LogServer.svclog" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" name="ServiceModelTraceListener" />
  </sharedListeners>
  <trace autoflush="true" />
</system.diagnostics>
```

If I apply this filter, there won't go a single message into the log...
So what am I doing wrong regarding the linked example above?

Without the filter the xml trace of a default message (method `ToUpper` invoked with string parameter `hello`) looks like this:

```
<E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent">
  <System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system">
    <EventID>0</EventID>
    <Type>3</Type>
    <SubType Name="Information">0</SubType>
    <Level>8</Level>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2011-05-27T17:53:53.9908714Z" />
    <Source Name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging" />
    <Correlation ActivityID="{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}" />
    <Execution ProcessName="WcfLoggingTest.Host.vshost" ProcessID="4324" ThreadID="12" />
    <Channel />
    <Computer>MY-Machine</Computer>
  </System>
  <ApplicationData>
    <TraceData>
      <DataItem>
        <MessageLogTraceRecord Time="2011-05-27T19:53:53.9908714+02:00" Source="TransportReceive" Type="System.ServiceModel.Channels.BufferedMessage" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/ServiceModel/Management/MessageTrace">
          <HttpRequest>
            <Method>POST</Method>
            <QueryString></QueryString>
            <WebHeaders>
              <VsDebuggerCausalityData>uIDPozEtlPQCjkhCodYdPWh6joUAAAAAamILDP7v3kG5sY6zKsB7HPPiLBWr+AVGmfFDQbk8GYAACQAA</VsDebuggerCausalityData>
              <SOAPAction>"http://myNamespace.org/IMyService/ToUpper"</SOAPAction>
              <Content-Length>157</Content-Length>
              <Content-Type>text/xml; charset=utf-8</Content-Type>
              <Accept-Encoding>gzip, deflate</Accept-Encoding>
              <Expect>100-continue</Expect>
              <Host>localhost:8731</Host>
            </WebHeaders>
          </HttpRequest>
          <s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
            <s:Header>
              <To s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">http://localhost:8731/Design_Time_Addresses/MyService/</To>
              <Action s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">http://myNamespace.org/IMyService/ToUpper</Action>
            </s:Header>
            <s:Body>
              <ToUpper xmlns="http://myNamespace.org/">
                <s>hello</s>
              </ToUpper>
            </s:Body>
          </s:Envelope>
        </MessageLogTraceRecord>
      </DataItem>
    </TraceData>
  </ApplicationData>
</E2ETraceEvent>
```

**Update:**
For for every body who's interested in the solution, I finally got it working with jasso's help, thanks:

```
<add xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">/soap:Envelope/soap:Header/a:Action[starts-with(text(),'http://myNamespace.org/IMyService/ToUpper')]</add>
```

I then edited my Interface and added the methods `Method1` till `Method3`. My goal was then to log everything except the messages related to `Method1` and `Method3`. I did this with the following filter:

```
<add xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">/soap:Envelope/soap:Header/a:Action[starts-with(text(),'http://myNamespace.org/IMyService/Method1')=false() and starts-with(text(),'http://myNamespace.org/IMyService/Method3')=false()]</add>
```

This way, only the messages related to `Invert`, `ToUpper` and `Method2` are logged.

It may be a cleaner approach to handle this with two seperate filters, but for the moment I'm quite happy with this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are using a wrong namespace for the `Action` element in your XPath expression

You have

```
xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"
... /a:Action[starts-with ...
```

and the document has

```
<Action s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">
```

So the namespaces differ, because `Action` element has a default namespace definition attached to it.

Also your XPath is searching for a `soap:Envelope` **root** element because your expression starts with a `/`. I'm not familiar with the framework, it might select a subtree from your example XML (the soap content) and then apply the XPath filter. If this is not the case and your XPath should produce a match on that given XML document, then you should start the expression with `//` or with a path to `soap:Envelope` element (like `/*/*/*/*/*/soap:Envelope`). Using `//` operator in the beginning is inefficient since it requires going through all the nodes in the whole document.

Comment: if I try this filter `<add xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">/soap:Envelope/soap:Header/a:Action[starts-with(text(),'http://myNamespace.org/IMyService/Invert')]</add>` there won't go a single message into the log :/

Comment: Also your first namespace (soap) is incorrect. Instead of `http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope` your document has `<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">` I didn't notice this another namespace error when I wrote my answer, sorry.

Comment: oh boy, I'm so blind... you're right, if I add the following filter, it works as expected :) `<add xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">/soap:Envelope/soap:Header/a:Action[starts-with(text(),'http://myNamespace.org/IMyService/ToUpper')]</add>` Thank you!

Comment: In case anyone is the same idiot like me and just tries to copy the XPath expression from the previous comment, be aware that there are some special characters ater the "/soap:Envelope" part that are not displayed in the browser and in Notepad++ too. They crashed my web.config, so just delete them and it will work (at least it did for me)

Answer (score 5):

Very thanks for the useful information!

According to my own study, to perform the filtering successfully, these key points must be enforced as well:

1. do not start the XPath expression with double "/", else the filtering will not work at all. Although this double "/" is correct regarding to XPath syntax (the same as what jasso pointed at May 27 23:06, 2011).
2. do not rely on the WCF Configuration Edit tool to choose the alias for the involved xml namespace. Till now it is found that "s12" does not work, but "s" or "s1a" is OK (Maybe it is a bug done by Microsoft, I am not sure).

Answer (score 0):

The XPath query is probably the problem. Try this simpler version:

```
<filters>
    <add xmlns:msgtr="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/ServiceModel/Management/MessageTrace" >//msgtr:SOAPAction[contains(.,'ToUpper')]</add>
</filters>
```

Comment: this filter seems to have no effect. If I apply it, there is no message filtered. It has the same effect as if I applied no filter.